# How do I handle duplicated symbols in a loadable NSBundle/plug-in?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, linker, nsbundle

Consider the following Cocoa project structure:

```
Host
|-- LoadablePlugIn
|   |-- Main.storyboard
|   |-- Info.plist
|   |-- TDWLPIClassOne.h
|   |-- TDWLPIClassOne.m
|   |-- TDWLPIClassTwo.h
|   |-- TDWLPIClassTwo.m
|-- TDWAppDelegate.h
|-- TDWAppDelegate.h
|-- TDWClassOne.h
|-- TDWClassOne.m
|-- TDWUtils.h
|-- TDWUtils.mm
|-- Base.lproj
|   `-- Main.storyboard
|-- Info.plist
`-- main.m
```

Here the root folder refers to sources of the `Host` target (the main executable target), while `LoadablePlugIn` refers to resources of an [embedded plug-in](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingCode/LoadingCode.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000052i) target with corresponding name. Both targets at the same time want to use `TDWUtils` symbols for their own purposes, so I add `TDWUtils.mm` to compile sources of both `Host` and `LoadablePlugIn` targets. It compiles and works without issues, however since the `LoadablePlugIn` is supposed to load during run-time the linker is not able to locate duplicated symbols of `TDWUtils.mm` in the binaries and I’m not sure if that is a robust scenario:

```objc
...
Class plugInPrincipalClass = [NSBundle bundleWithURL:loadablePlugInURL].principalClass;
NSWindowController *windowController = [plugInPC instantiateInitialController];
...
```

Should I compile `LoadablePlugIn` with hidden symbols compiler flag (like `-fvisibility=hidden`) or use any other technique to prevent the name collision or can I just leave it as is because in both binaries the symbols of `TDWUtils` have exactly the same implementation?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you could factor out the duplicate code into a framework that is linked against by each module that requires it.

So, in the final app, you'd have a structure like the following:

```
AppName.app/Contents/MacOS/AppName

AppName.app/Contents/Frameworks/TDWUtils.framework

AppName.app/Contents/PlugIns/Loadable.plugin/Contents/MacOS/Loadable
```

The Dynamic Library Install Name Base (`DYLIB_INSTALL_NAME_BASE`) for the `TDWUtils.framework` should be `@rpath` (i.e. avoid using `@executable_path` or `@loader_path` in the install name). Using `@rpath`  makes it easy to share the same library among code that's located at various locations within an app bundle. With `@rpath`, it becomes the responsibility of module that's doing the loading to specify where the library is in relation to itself. You do this by adding a Runpath Search Path (`LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS`) entry for each library the loading module needs.

For the main app executable, it could be either `@executable_path/../Frameworks` or `@loader_path/../Frameworks`.

For the plugin, it becomes `@loader_path/../../../../Frameworks`. (Using `@executable_path` would not work, since a plugin isn't executed, it's just loaded). At runtime, `@loader_path` in this case becomes `AppName.app/Contents/PlugIns/Loadable.plugin/Contents/MacOS/Loadable`, so to get to the Frameworks directory, you have to go up 4 levels to get to the Contents, folder, then back down into the Frameworks folder.